# Boost Jam vs Jam

Tags: boost, bjam

I recently built the Boost libraries in Linux and noticed the package needed an executable called bjam in order to do the build.  Is bjam related to [jam](http://freetype.sourceforge.net/jam/index.html)?  If it is related to jam, did they somehow extend (or even dumb-down) bjam?  Is it used only for building Boost libraries or is it a general build tool for anything?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Boost.Jam originally was a slightly modified version of classic Jam. It gradually diverged very far. Boost.Jam is actually a low-level engine component of Boost.Build and is not meant to be used independently. Boost.Build is a general build tool, it's not tied to C++ Boost libraries in any way.

Comment: If I ever release build tool I think I'll call it Boost.Jam.Build.

Answer (score 3):

Boost jam (bjam) is an extension, more like forked version, of perforce jam.  It is *not* only for building Boost libraries.  It can be used as a general build tool.  There is also ft-jam for that matter.  All incantations spawned from perforce jam based on my research of the tool.  I believe Boost Jam V2 is so far removed from the original Perforce Jam implementation that they aren't the same tool except at a very, very high level.